# EF Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When i try to run this code i get an exception from EntityFramework that it is Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Workflow1.Step1' of type 'Step1'. I have tried to blindly configure it in OnModelCreating with no luck, any idea how to solve this?

The code works fine if i remove DbQuery but i want it there so i can Query on that data without doing an Include from a workflow, and still be sure that no changes are made directly inside the step.

```
public class Workflow1
{
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }

        public Guid Step1Id {get; private set;}
        public Step1 Step1 {get; private set;}

        public Guid Step2Id {get; private set;}
        public Step2 Step2 {get; private set;}

        public Guid Step3Id {get; private set;}
        public Step3 Step3 {get; private set;}
}

public class Workflow2
{
        public Guid Step2Id {get; private set;}
        public Step2 Step2 {get; private set;}

        public Guid Step4Id {get; private set;}
        public Step5 Step4 {get; private set;}
}

public class Step1 
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) :base(options)
    {}

    public DbSet<Workflow1> Workflow1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Workflow2> Workflow2 { get; set; }

    public DbQuery<Step1> Step1 { get; set; }
    public DbQuery<Step3> Step2 { get; set; }
    public DbQuery<Step3> Step3 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code works fine if i remove DbQuery but i want it there so i can Query on that data without doing an Include from a workflow, and still be sure that no changes are made directly inside the step.

No! You cannot do that because [EF Core Query Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) documentation clearly says that:

> Entities cannot contain navigation properties to query types.

So for mapping you have to make `Step1`,`Step2`, `Step3` as `DbSet<>` because `Workflow1` is `DbSet<>` or Entity Type type.